# pyspark adding values with common set of keys (python)

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I have This RDD:

```
[('19', '1004', '129'),
 ('17', '1004', '129'),
 ('9', '1001', '99'),
 ('3', '1003', '89'),
 ('19', '1002', '149'),
 ('16', '1002', '149'),
 ('16', '1002', '149')]
```

I want to add the values only if both of the keys match.
for ex:

```
('**16**', '**1002**', '149'),
('**16**', '**1002**', '149')
```

Desired output is

```
[('19', '1004', '129'),
 ('17', '1004', '129'),
 ('9', '1001', '99'),
 ('3', '1003', '89'),
 ('19', '1002', '149'),
 ('16', '1002', '298')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you want is [`reduceByKey()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.reduceByKey), but your data isn't quite in a format that can be used by that function.

- You need to convert the string values into integer values
- You need to convert tuples from the form `(k1, k2, v)` to `((k1, k2), v)`

This ought to work:

```
# Prepare for reduce operation
r = r.map(lambda t: ((t[0], t[1]), int(t[2])))

# Add matching items
from operator import add
r = r.reduceByKey(add)

# If desired, convert back to your original form
r = r.map(lambda t: (t[0][0], t[0][1], str(t[1])))
```